# "Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing" when configuring javaagent in IntelliJ

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, javaagents

This one took me way too long to figure out.

I was trying to configure a Java agent for a test execution in IntelliJ by configuring the following VM option in the Run/Debug Configuration:

```
-javaagent:~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-instrument/5.0.4.RELEASE/spring-instrument-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar
```

It kept failing with

```
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : ~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-instrument/5.0.4.RELEASE/spring-instrument-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
```

Similar questions talk about actually corrupted jar files or spaces in the path which didn't apply to my case.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `~` in the path. It doesn't seem to get resolved by the execution started IntelliJ. After replacing it with the full path starting from root it worked fine.

I expect there exist alternatives based on setting the working directory and using a relative path from there, but an absolute path seems the simplest to understand and debug.